# Why can't you use dynamic nat on server?

Tags: nat, ip

We use static NAT for servers in a LAN. But using dynamic NAT doesn't have any effect, then why is it a standard? Is it because of the overhead faced by the server, to map each connection/request to it's local ip and vice-versa. Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to use dynamic NAT? I don't see what your issue is. More information would also help.

Comment: It's just a doubt. Is it feasible to use dynamic NAT for a server in a LAN? (It was my first post, sorry for any mistakes.)

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  Specifically, what do you mean by the statement "using dynamic NAT doesn't have any effect" and to which standard are you referring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're confused about the usual uses of static- and dynamic NAT.

**Static** is used on the outside router/firewall to expose a server/service located inward which wouldn't normally be reachable from the outside. (static: nailed in place, permanently mapped inward.)

**Dynamic** is used to enable inward transportation of return traffic for outgoing connections; so a web browser on a system with a private IP is dynamically mapped to a public address as the packets egress, and then the return traffic is mapped back for ingress. (dynamic: the inside end points change so the mappings are changing too.)

Comment: For those companies with few public addresses, generally private IP's are dynamic NAT or PAT. PAT (Port Address Translation) assigns each public PC a port then translates their traffic back to the private IP during ingress traffic.